# I can access kivy camera through OpenCV but there is no display

Tags: python, opencv, kivy

I am integrating a computer vision project into kivy framework so that it can be used in android devices.
Project is about liveness detection, it instructs you to turn your head, smile, blink etc. It works really fine in OpenCV, but I need to integrate it into kivy framework. I found this example in kivy, thinking this is similar to my problem.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import cv2

class KivyCamera(Image):
    def __init__(self, capture, fps, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = capture
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / fps)

    def update(self, dt):
        faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("Resources/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")  # added

        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:

            frameGray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # added
            faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(frameGray, 1.1, 4)  # added

            for (x, y, w, h) in faces:  # added
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)  # added

            # convert it to texture
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            # display image from the texture
            self.texture = image_texture


class CamApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.my_camera = KivyCamera(capture=self.capture, fps=30)
        return self.my_camera

    def on_stop(self):
        #without this, app will not exit even if the window is closed
        self.capture.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CamApp().run()
```

This works really fine, it detects faces and it puts squares around them.
My main program asks 4 questions, like "blink, smile" and these questions prints on OpenCV camera.

I tried to integrate my OpenCV code and functionally it works, there are no errors and I can see it detects my movements from console prints. The problem is I can't get any display on screen, it opens camera and gives me white screen. That is the code:

```
    import imutils
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import cv2
import random

import f_liveness_detection
import questions


class KivyCamera(Image):
    def __init__(self, capture, fps, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = capture
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / fps)  
    def update(self, dt):
        
        COUNTER, TOTAL = 0, 0
        counter_ok_questions = 0
        counter_ok_consecutives = 0
        limit_consecutives = 3
        limit_questions = 4  # 6
        counter_try = 0
        limit_try = 50

        def show_image(text, color=(0, 0, 255)):
            ret, im = self.capture.read()
            im = imutils.resize(im, width=720)
            cv2.putText(im, text, (10, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, color, 2)
            frame_to_texture(im)

        def frame_to_texture(image):
            buf1 = cv2.flip(image, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                size=(image.shape[1], image.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            # display image from the texture
            self.texture = image_texture

        ret, frame = self.capture.read()

        for i_questions in range(0, limit_questions):
            
            index_question = random.randint(0, 3)  
            question = questions.question_bank(
                index_question)  

            show_image(question) 

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

            for i_try in range(limit_try): 
                ret, im = self.capture.read()
                im = imutils.resize(im, width=720)
                im = cv2.flip(im, 1)
               
                TOTAL_0 = TOTAL
                out_model = f_liveness_detection.detect_liveness(im, COUNTER, TOTAL_0)
                TOTAL = out_model['total_blinks']
                COUNTER = out_model['count_blinks_consecutives']
                dif_blink = TOTAL - TOTAL_0
                if dif_blink > 0:
                    blinks_up = 1
                else:
                    blinks_up = 0

                challenge_res = questions.challenge_result(question, out_model, blinks_up)

                show_image(question)

                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break

                if challenge_res == "pass":
                    show_image(question + " : basarili")  # !!!!!!!

                    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                        break

                    counter_ok_consecutives += 1
                    if counter_ok_consecutives == limit_consecutives:
                        counter_ok_questions += 1
                        counter_try = 0
                        counter_ok_consecutives = 0
                        break
                    else:
                        continue

                elif challenge_res == "fail":
                    counter_try += 1
                    show_image(question + " : basarisiz")
                elif i_try == limit_try - 1:
                    break

            if counter_ok_questions == limit_questions:
                while True:
                    show_image("CANLILIK TESPITI BASARILI", color=(0, 255, 0))

                    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                        break
            elif i_try == limit_try - 1:
                while True:
                    show_image("CANLILIK TESPITI BASARISIZ")

                    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                        break
                break

            else:
                continue
            # convert it to texture
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            # display image from the texture
            self.texture = image_texture


class CamApp(App):  
    def build(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
        self.my_camera = KivyCamera(capture=self.capture,
                                    fps=30) 
        return self.my_camera 

    def on_stop(self):
        self.capture.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CamApp().run()
```

I tried a lot of things but I can't seem to manage it. Any help will be appreciated deeply.

Comment: use `print()` to sea what you have in variables. OR learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: start from scratch, build that code up piece by piece. figure out what makes it stop working.

Comment: Actually it is working, I mean there is no error and it is a functional program. It prints commands on console, camera opens and I can see it detects my movements by console prints, "successfull". It just won't display, there is just a white screen. I edited code by detecting what's necessary and what isn't. I added methods to make it functional but still there is no display.

Comment: Hello - any luck with this? We have the same frame_to_texture code and I have the same issue as you. My code worked fine on a previous display and the issue only happened once I changed the LCD for my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not solve this issue. Good luck with yours.

Comment: Any luck guys? This issue is driving me insane.